# How can i know if the user press on the buttons Ctrl+K?

Tags: silverlight

I define this in the page1 in the 'OnNavigatedTo' method

```
page1.keyEventHandler += (s, k) => 
{
     if( k.Key == Key.P )
     {
            // Do Something ... 
     }
}
```

But i need to know if the user pressed on two keys together ... i need to know if the user
pressed on the     Key.Ctrl+Key.P

How can i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
page1.keyEventHandler += (s, k) => {

  if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && k.Key == Key.P) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't nice way of doing this. You'll need to fire 2 events. One for each key, [like so](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/220965/529527.aspx):

```
private bool KeyADown = false;
private bool KeyBDown = false;

private void LayoutRoot_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        KeyADown = true;
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.B)
    {
        KeyBDown = true;
    }

    // check for Ctrl+A+B
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        if (KeyADown && KeyBDown)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+A+B detected");
        }
    }
}

private void LayoutRoot_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        KeyADown = false;
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.B)
    {
        KeyBDown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that the original poster just wanted to detect a CTRL+Key combination, and not a full key chord, so my solution should suffice. Otherwise this approach is great.